# IntelliVIEW OCX Loading Issue

Tags: windows-7, vb6, windows-7-x64, ocx

We are migrating over from an XP machine to a Windows 7 machine for our programming. We were able to get the VB6 IDE installed just fine, and after tweaking our VBP to use MSCOMCTRL.OCX 2.0 instead of 2.1, we got our VBP to load 90% correctly, except for one OCX.

We use a program called IntelliVIEW to generate documents for us. The OCX file  we use on our XP machine refuses to load on the Windows 7 machine. It won't load in either Windows 7 OR XP mode, whereas it loads fine on the other, original XP machine. I tried regsvr32 on the OCX to no avail. The OCX in question is "iview3.ocx". The line in the VBP referring to the OCX is as follows:

```
Object={7E90FB46-785E-4FDE-8DAE-A9C01438595C}#1.0#0; iview3.ocx
```

Any help in getting this to load would be AWESOME, as it's our final hurdle to this migration. Thanks.

---

**EDIT**

I guess we can disregard this OCX after all, as it has actually been depreciated in our program. It was only called one time long ago in a form that we no longer use. Thanks for the time, guys.

Comment: What exactly does, "I tried regsvr32 on the OCX to no avail." mean? Does regsvr32 show an error? Most likely, you'll have to run the 3rd party control's installer as Administrator as it may also install some dependencies.

Comment: I mean that regsvr32 registers the file just fine, but VB6 still won't load it.

Comment: compile your program in the XP machine then create the installer for it from the same machine. the installer is wise enough to know what component to incorporate in exe. reinstall it in w7 machine, the installer will install and register ocx for you. now try to load your project in w7

Comment: You may need the original developer's installer and product key from the vendor.  Just hacking around isn't going to put design-time license information into the new machine and 3rd party controls often used a different scheme for this than Microsoft controls did.

Comment: I guess we can disregard this OCX after all, as it has actually been depreciated in our program. It was only called one time long ago in a form that we no longer use. Thanks for the time, guys.